# Is there a difference between IS NULL and IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NULL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, isnull

Is there a difference between `value IS NULL` and `value IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NULL`?

Is it the same for each SQL dialect?

Comment: If `value` is `NULL`, then the first returns "true" and the second "false".  They are nothing alike.

Comment: "*Is it the same for each SQL dialect?*" - To my knowledge Postgres is the only DBMS that supports the standard `is distinct` operator. So the answer to that is: no

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name whoopsie! Correct, the `NOT` was missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` predicate is part of the SQL standard (SQL:2003)
However, it isn't yet fully adopted by all the DBMS.
Actually, only a few... Well, PostgreSql has.

You can see it as a "NULL tolerant equal"

To compare:

```
(1 = 1)  --> true
(1 = 0)  --> false
(1 = null) --> unknown/null
(null = null) --> unknown/null

(1 IS NULL) --> false
(null IS NULL) --> true

(1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 1) --> true
(1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 0) --> false
(1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM null)  --> false
(null IS NOT DISTINCT FROM null)  --> true
```

So the main difference between `IS NULL` versus `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`?
Basically,  the `IS NULL` is used to check if an element is empty.
While `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` compares 2 elements.

Used in a WHERE clause then this:

```
WHERE (x IS NOT DISTINCT FROM y)
```

Has a Standard SQL alternative:

```
WHERE (x = y OR (x IS NULL AND y IS NULL))
```

Comment: Note that the proposed standard SQL alternative in this answer is not equivalent to IS NOT DISTINCT FROM for all use cases. If x is 1 and y is null, the alternative will return null, not false. That's fine in a WHERE clause (because WHERE null does the same thing as WHERE false), but in e.g. a SELECT clause, the proposed alternative would not be equivalent to IS NOT DISTINCT FROM.

Comment: Here's a full alternative that returns True or False in all cases, and never returns unknown/null: `((x IS NOT NULL AND y IS NOT NULL AND x = y) OR (x IS NULL AND y IS NULL))`

Answer (score 2):

There are subtle differences between these tests; compare

```
SELECT ROW(NULL, NULL) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NULL;
```

and

```
SELECT ROW(NULL, NULL) IS NULL;
```

Comment: `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` is part of the SQL standard, it's not a Postgres extension

Comment: @laurenz-albe Could you please explain why these 2 examples produce different results? What's the point of these results to differ?

Comment: There is not much sense in this. Compound types and NULL is one of those places where the standard committee must have taken the wrong drugs. I just wanted to point out that these expressions are not totally identical.